# Stop thread from other form (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms.
In form2 I have 1 thread.
I have to stop it from form1.

I tried:

```
...
_Form1.threadname = stop()
...
```

But I'll get this error:

```
Error   1   ... threadname is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'.
```

How can I solve this?
I don't know what to set to public.

Comment: I took out your `XAML` tag since there does not seem to be any reason for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a field that is declared as follows

```
Private threadname As String
```

In order to access it from other classes this needs to be `Friend` or `Public`.

```
Public threadname As String
```